# Debugger implementation - Step over issue

Tags: debugging, breakpoints

I am currently writing a debugger for a script virtual machine.
The compiler for the scripts generates debug information, such as function entry points, variable scopes, names, instruction to line mappings, etc.

However, and have run into an issue with step-over.

Right now, I have the following:
1. Look up the current IP
2. Get the source line from that
3. Get the next (valid) source line
4. Get the IP where the next valid source line starts
5. Set a temporary breakpoint at that instruction

or: if the next source line no longer belongs to the same function, set the temp  breakpoint at the next valid source line after return address.

So far this works well. However, I seem to be having problems with jumps.

For example, take the following code:

```
n = 5; // Line A
if(n == 5) // Line B
{
    foo(); // Line C
}
else
{
    bar(); // Line D
    --n;
}
```

Given this code, if I'm on line B and choose to step-over, the IP determined for the breakpoint will be on line C. If, however, the conditional jump evaluates to false, it should be placed on line D. Because of this, the step-over wouldn't halt at the expected location (or rather, it wouldn't halt at all).

There seems to be little information on debugger implementation of this specific issue out there. However, I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132742/Writing-Windows-Debugger-Part-2). While this is for a native debugger on Windows, the theory still holds true.

It seems though that the author has not considered this issue, either, in section "Implementing Step-Over" as he says:

> ```
> 1. The UI-threads calls CDebuggerCore::ResumeDebugging with EResumeFlag set to StepOver.
> This tells the debugger thread (having the debugger-loop) to put IBP on next line.
> 2. The debugger-thread locates next executable line and address (0x41141e), it places an IBP on that location.
> 3. It calls then ContinueDebugEvent, which tells the OS to continue running debuggee.
> 4. The BP is now hit, it passes through EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT and reaches at EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP. Both these steps are same, including instruction reversal, EIP reduction etc.
> 5. It again calls HaltDebugging, which in turn, awaits user input.
> ```

Again:

**The debugger-thread locates next executable line and address (0x41141e), it places an IBP on that location.**

This statement does not seem to hold true in cases where jumps are involved, though.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If so, do you have any tips on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so since this seems to be a bit of black magic, in this particular case the most intelligent thing was to enumerate the instruction where the next line starts (or the instruction stream ends + 1), and then run that many instructions before halting again.

The only gotcha was that I have to keep track of the stack frame in case CALL is executed; those instructions should run without counting in case of step-over.

Answer (score 2):

Since this thread comes in Google first when searching for "debugger implement step over". I'll share my experiences regarding the x86 architecture.

You start first by implementing step into: This is basically single stepping on the instructions and checking whether the line corresponding to the current EIP changes. (You use either the DIA SDK or the read the dwarf debug data to find out the current line for an EIP).

In the case of step over: before single stepping to the next instruction, you'll need to check if the current instruction is a CALL instuction. If it's a CALL instruction then put a temporary breakpoint on the instruction following it and continue execution till the execution stops (then remove it). In this case you effectively stepped over function calls literally in the assembly level and so in the source too.

No need to manage stack frames (unless you'll need to deal with single line recursive functions). This analogy can be applied to other architectures as well.